# Forvalues-loop showing incorrect syntax

Tags: loops, stata

I want to generate variable names that depend on given variable `games`.
For example, if `games` is given as 3, the result is

`game1` = list of uniformly distributed values

`game2` = same, etc.

While there are multiple examples and answers on similar questions, I cannot see why my code cannot produce the results I want

Stata shows syntax error for the following loop:

```
set obs 1000

forvalues i = 1(1)games {
generate game`i' = runiform()
}
```

Comment: This isn't complete code until you have a definition of `games`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `games` really a variable in Stata's sense? Holding the same constant again and again is unnecessary and inefficient.

The problem is that `forvalues` expects to see numbers; it won't perform evaluations on the fly. But other parts of Stata will do that.

If you know you want just 3 variables then you could do just this:

```
clear 
set obs 1000

forvalues i = 1/3 {
    generate game`i' = runiform()
}
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
clear 
set obs 1000
local games = 3     
forvalues i = 1/`games' {
    generate game`i' = runiform()
}
```

That does not contradict my opening paragraph. All macro evaluations are performed before any command is executed; thus `forvalues` sees 3, not a local macro name.

If you were really were holding a constant in a variable, then this would work:

```
clear 
gen games = 3 
set obs 1000
forvalues i = 1/`=games[1]' {
    generate game`i' = runiform()
}
```